# Integer parseint в optional

Tags: java

Есть вот такой код

```
Integer page = Optional.ofNullable(request.queryParams("page")).map(p -> {
            try {
                return Integer.parseInt(p);
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                return null;
            }
        }).orElse(null);
```

как избавиться от try catch внутри него, но при этом, что бы когда параметр page будет строкой, не вылилась ошибка?

Comment: Это ж джава.. Нормально не избавишься...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
Integer page = Optional.of("abc").filter(e -> e.chars().allMatch(Character::isDigit)).map(Integer::parseInt).orElse(null);
```

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете удалить все символы кроме цифр в строке и если результат не пустой, то можете передать его функции parseInt, но лучше valueOf, так как он работает с пулом интов